# How to match nested property without using the nested property in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a search functionality for products using ElasticSearch. We need to show relevant results by category, title and brand, depending on what the user has entered into the search box. For example, if you write Apple Laptop, you want to show only Apple Laptops. We don't want to show Apple Watches, Apple iPhones, Lenovo Laptops etc.

The problem is that the function works perfectly if we have category_title. But, category is actually a nested object with title and name properties.

Initial query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query":  "apple~ AND laptop~",
                        "fields": [
                            "category_title",
                            "title",
                            "brand"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So the query should look like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query":  "apple~ AND laptop~",
                        "fields": [
                            "category.title",
                            "title",
                            "brand"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I keep the same search behaviour and still being able to search by category.title?

Schema:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

I'm updating my answer and sharing a solution. It's not the best one but can help you.

Elasticsearch [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html)

```
PUT product_stack2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "brand": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "copy_to": "search_field"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "search_field"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "search_field"
          }
        }
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "search_field"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "search_field"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
PUT product_stack2/_doc/1
{
  "name": "1",
  "brand": "apple",
  "category": {
    "name": "1",
    "title": "laptops"
  },
  "title": "Macbook Pro"
}
```

---

```
GET product_stack2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "apple~ AND laptop~",
            "fields": [
              "search_field"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: But i think results will be different. For example "apple" might not be in the category and will result in empty hits. Hence, no products will be found at all.

Comment: If there is no match with apple, it's better to not return anything.

Comment: You're not getting it. You can't split it in two queries because it'll break. It must done within one query. Apple will be matched as brand, laptop as category. My version makes sense and would work. Your version will cause empty results. Run this query in your head and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Nick. Is the raw data have `category.title` and `category.brand` fields? If so, is it make sense to use only that fields?
Please share a couple of sample document to understand more.

Comment: Of course, give me a moment, thank you! Let me elaborate a little bit more why it won't work with two queries: Take "apple laptop" for example. You'll search this in category.title in one query, and then in title and brand in another query. Apple is part of the brand field, but it does not exist in the category.title field. Which means second query will have no matches and since it's a must query - the whole response will be empty at the end (0 hits)

Comment: I updated the post, uploaded the ES products schema.

Comment: Thanks for adding schema, it'd be great if you can also add an example document. Also, I updated my answer please check if it works for you

Comment: ```{"name": "1", "brand": "apple", "category": {"name": "1", "title": "laptops"}, "title": "Macbook Pro"}``` 

Here is an example product

Comment: Also, the updated query still wouldn't work unfortunately. Here is a similar problem without an answer to understand it better: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/combine-normal-and-nested-fields-with-query-string/315502

You want to do cross field match on the whole sentence, on all keywords from the sentence in one query.

It's different to check if "apple laptop" exists in title,brand,category , or to check if "apple laptop" exists in title,brand AND/OR category. Major difference.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm updating my answer and sharing a solution, It's not the best one but can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused as to how nested fields work. From your comment, this is an example product:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "brand": "apple",
    "category": {
        "name": "1",
        "title": "laptops"
    },
    "title": "Macbook Pro"
}
```

But in this case, category is *not* a nested field. It internally translates to `"category.name": "1"` and `"category.title": "laptops"`. If category indeed is a nested field, it would typically look like this:

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "brand": "apple",
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "real",
            "title": "laptops"
        },
        {
            "name": "fake",
            "title": "computers"
        },
        {
            "name": "real",
            "title": "macbooks"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Macbook Pro"
}
```

The nesting allows you to query each child document separately (eg. only match a result if `category.name = real` *and* `category.title = laptops` in the same element of that array).

But to me, it sounds like you don't actually care if `apple` and `laptop` need to both be in the same element of that nested category. You just care that these two words are there. If that is the case, then you should either **(1)** don't label that field as "nested" or **(2)** or you can add an additional flag `include_in_parent` in the mapping. After which you can use `category.title` in the original simplified query in your post.

If for some mind blowing reason you need to adjust your query to fit the Elasticsearch mapping (instead of adjusting the mapping to fit the query) then the only way I can think to do what you're trying to do where it functions similar to having a category.title field is this ugliness which only gets worse with more keywords:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
       {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "apple~",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "brand"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "category",
                  "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "apple~",
                      "default_field": "category.title"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "laptop~",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "brand"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "category",
                  "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "laptop~",
                      "default_field": "category.title"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```